# ASP.NET Core 1.1 web application does not start when running with IIS Express in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I've recently installed Visual Studio 2017 Professional and have just created the boilerplate ASP.NET Core Web Application

This is what happens when I hit Run (With IIS Express):

[image]

And this is what Visual Studio 2017's Output window says:

> The program '[8260] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -2147450749
>   (0x80008083).
>
> The program '[6476] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Steps to fix?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42121332/visual-studio-2017-doesnt-run-core-apps-with-iis-express/42143720#42143720 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this worked for me: Install the x86 SDK...

https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core

Comment: Installing x86 sdk made no difference to issue on hand in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a bug as per [Visual Studio 2017 Doesn't Run Core Apps with IIS Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42121332/visual-studio-2017-doesnt-run-core-apps-with-iis-express/42143720#42143720).

And that the current status is fixed pending release: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/11391/aspnet-core-iis-express-httplocalhost51733-failed.html

And that the workarounds meanwhile are probably:

- `dotnet run`
- Publish to local IIS. Which is working for me.
- (Untested: downgrade from core-1.1 to core-1.0)

If you aren't familiar with VS2017/asp.net: You probably have the Debug toolbar visible which shows you a dropdown with a green arrow and '**IIS Express**'. Click on that and you should see a 'Run {yourprojectname}' option. This is the equivalent of `dotnet run {yourprojectname}` from the commandline

Comment: I tried running the project itself, rather than via IIS Express, but I still get the dotnet error.

Comment: If you cd to the project directory and do `dotnet run` do you see any more helpful error?

Comment: Or, having chosen 'Run {yourprojectname}' in the debugger toolbar, does it launch in debug? If so, it should break on exceptions and tell you waht the problem is

Answer (score 1):

*'The program '[8260] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -2147450749 (0x80008083).'*

Could be a x86 x64 related thing. (Same for Console Core Apps)

If you have installed multiple versions of .NET Core like so:
[image]

You need to set the order in the path environment variable:

[image]

So that the one you want to use appears first and then (re-)start Visual Studio.
To check which dotnet is currently "active" run: dotnet --info in the console.

Comment: This solved my issue. I removed the (x86) version from my Path, restarted Visual Studio (to be sure) and then tried again. This time it ran the project fine.